# Text color in link, which is selected by a ID, is overriding the parent link color of a different ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

Kind of hard to explain, so here's some code.

So I have this CSS, which makes all links an orangish color. It encompases the entire page.

```css
#pageContent a:link,a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color: #EE4036; 
}
```

And then I have an element of id sideMenu somewhere within the pageContent id,

```css
#sideMenu a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
    color:#58595B;

}
```

The problem is that for some reason sideMenu's given link color is overwriting pageContent's link color for links that aren't children of sideMenu.

for example, if I had

```html
<div id="pageContent" >
   <a>this text should be #EE4036</a>
   <div id="sideMenu">
      <a>this text should be #58595B</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

sideMenu's `<a>` text content would get set to the color #58595B as expected, but so would pageContent's, which is what I wouldn't expect.

I'm a bit new to CSS so I feel like I'm missing some super obvious rule and google isn't helping at all. So, anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to prefix each selector with the ID:

```css
#sideMenu a:link, #sideMenu a:visited, #sideMenu a:hover, #sideMenu a:active {
    color:#58595B;
}
```

Currently, your selector says match "links that are descendants of an element with ID "slideMenu", links that have been visited, links that are being hovered, and active links".

Basically, when you use the comma to create a [group of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping), each individual selector is completely independent. There is no relationship between them.

Comment: @gilly3 - Thanks for the syntax highlighting edit. I wish it would get better at recognising CSS automatically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew it was something simple! I'll select your answer as soon as it lets me, for some reason it's telling me I need to wait 7 mins.

Comment: @James - Me too... seems strange it doesn't work automatically yet even on questions like this that are tagged only as `css`.  There's no ambiguity.

Comment: @Michael - You're welcome, glad I could help :) Yeah, you can't accept an answer within the first 15 minutes of asking your question.

Comment: @gilly3 I seemed to have the same problem with my CSS code before you fixed it... any pointers for getting it right next time? Not entirely sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @James Allardice: [I feel your pain :(](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions)

Comment: @Michael - You just need to put this on its own line above your code: `<!-- language: lang-css -->`. That will work for various languages if they don't get automatically picked up. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) for more info!

Comment: @Michael - You didn't do anything wrong.  SO's syntax highlighting *usually* does a good job of identifying the code language and applying the appropriate highlighting.  But, I've never seen it identify CSS code on its own.  So you can manually indicate the language with comments such as `<!-- language: lang-css -->`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for more details.

Comment: Thanks! BoltClock's link provided a pretty good explanation of why this is happening with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are actually redefining the same rule. You must write down each time the `#sideMenu` or `#pageContent`. Here it is:

```css
#pageContent a:link, #pageContent a:visited, #pageContent a:hover, #pageContent a:active {
    color: #EE4036; 
}
#sideMenu a:link, #sideMenu a:visited, #sideMenu a:hover, #sideMenu a:active {
    color: #58595B; 
}
```

Voila. Hope it helps.

Comment: This did help, but unfortunately the other guy answered it before you. Gave you an upvote.